# Android search widget crash on touch after serach

Tags: android, search, android-actionbar

In my activity,I have a search widget in the actionbar. Clicking search icon expands searchview and when user types a test, the list is filtered as per the text. All this functionality works well. After searching once if we touch the searchview to edit the search string , the app crashes. Any touch event after first search crashes.

```
SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search)
            .getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
            .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
   searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    menuItem.setOnActionExpandListener(new OnActionExpandListener() {...
```

What could be the reason for this .

searchable.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        />
```

optionsmenu :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
    android:icon="@drawable/btn_search_bg"
    android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/search_title"/>
 <item
    android:id="@+id/miActionProgress"
    android:title="Loading..."
    android:visible="false"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/action_view_progress" />
```

The log says `12-17 11:23:04.249  32561-32561E/InputEventReceiver﹕ Exception dispatching input event.
12-17 11:23:04.249  32561-32561 E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
12-17 11:23:04.254  32561-32561 E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
            at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1416)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:861)
            at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:402)
            at android.widget.Editor$InsertionPointCursorController.getHandle(Editor.java:3883)
            at android.widget.Editor$InsertionPointCursorController.show(Editor.java:3862)
            at android.widget.Editor.onTouchUpEvent(Editor.java:1670)
            at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:8274)
            at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8486)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2541)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2234)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2541)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2234)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2541)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2234)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2541)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2234)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2541)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2234)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2541)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2234)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2541)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2234)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2541)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2234)
            at

Comment: post your 'menu' and 'searchable' xml files

Comment: it tries to call `getDrawable` with resId == 0, try to make your menu.xml as simple as possible to find out if it has anything to do with the bug

Comment: i removed the icon from menu as thats where drawable is used but still same crash

Comment: did you do own custom theming? if so, remove it for testing

Comment: it the custome theme i had <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@ style/PopupMenuTextView</item> which was causing the crash  <style name="PopupMenuTextView" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.TextView">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
        <item name="android:drawablePadding">25dp</item>
    </style>

Comment: I am not sure why it caused the crash . I tried by removing each line is PopupMenuTextView to find if its any particular item causing issue but it always happened

Comment: so removing the custom theme helped or not?

Comment: yes , modified custom theme. Add you comment as answer so i can accept